# Regular expression with a set with a character followed by a character

Tags: regex

I'm writing a regular expression in Java for capturing some word without spaces.
The word can contain only letter, number, hyphens and dot.
The character set `[\w+\-\\.]` work well.
Now I want to edit the set for allowing a single space after the dot.
How I have to edit my regular expression?

Comment: Is there more than one dot allowed? Could you show us some input/output?

Comment: I want to capture simple name like "smith" and more complex name like "mrs. smith"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add an [alternation](http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) that matches this additional requirement

```
([\w\-.]|(?<=\.) )+
```

See it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?38ape)

`(?<=\.)` is a [lookbehind assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html). It ensures that space is only matched, if it is preceded by a dot.

Other hints:

- `\w` contains the underscore and matches per default only ASCII letters/digits. If you care about Unicode, use either the modifier `UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS` to enable Unicode for `\w` or use the [Unicode properties](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html#prop) `\p{L}` and `\p{Nd}` to match Unicode letters and digits.
- You don't need to escape the dot in a character class.
- You have `\w+` in your character class, are you aware, that you just add the "+" character to the accepted characters?

Comment: You forgot to mention the `+` in the character class.  I'm pretty sure that's an error.

Comment: No, I meant the plus sign is *inside* the character class: `[\w+\-.]`.  The OP didn't list `+` as one of the allowed characters, so that's probably not what he meant.  We see that kind of error a lot from people who are still fuzzy on the difference between square brackets and parentheses in regexes.

Comment: @AlanMoore, sorry totally overlooked this difference, between the char class and the allowed characters. Added a point to this.

Comment: All the proposed solutions works, thank you all, I learned a lot of things about regular expressions today :)

Answer (score 0):

In case of a dot followed by a space, I suppose this pattern should be neither the first, nor the last in the matched string? You may want to enclose it in word boundaries `\b`:

```
([0-9A-Za-z-]|\b\.( \b)?)+
```

I deliberately did not use `\w`, to exclude underscores.

Comment: All the proposed solutions works, thank you all, I learned a lot of things about regular expressions today :)

Answer (score 0):

For allowing ONLY a single space after the dot you can use this regex:

```
^(?!.*?\. {2})[\w.-]+$
```

- You don't need to escape dot OR hyphen inside character class
- `(?!.*?\. {2})` is a negative lookahead that disallows 2 or more spaces after a dot

Comment: All the proposed solutions works, thank you all, I learned a lot of things about regular expressions today :)